# Why null is showing in chrom's console->application->localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am using the code far below and there is **null** showing up before the actual value of `storeArrObj` on my chrome's localStorage area. Why is that ?
[image]

Full Code

```
<label>First Name: </label><input type="text" id="firstNameSto"><br>
<label>Last Name: </label><input type="text" id="lastNameSto"><br>
<button type="submit" id="fetchDetails">Submit and Display</button>
<div id="displayStorage"></div>

<script>
    document.getElementById('fetchDetails').addEventListener('click',storageFunction);
    function storageFunction(){
        var firstNameSto = document.getElementById('firstNameSto').value;
        var lastNameSto = document.getElementById('lastNameSto').value;
        var storageArr = [];
        var storageObj = {
            firstName: firstNameSto,
            lastName: lastNameSto
        }
        if (localStorage.getItem('storageArrObj') === ""){
            storageArr.push(storageObj);
            var storeObj = JSON.stringify(storageArr);
            localStorage.setItem('storageArrObj', storeObj);
        } else {
            var parseStor = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storageArrObj'));
            storageArr.push(parseStor);
            storageArr.push(storageObj);
            var storeObj = JSON.stringify(storageArr);
            localStorage.setItem('storageArrObj',storeObj);
        }
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('storageArrObj'));

    }
</script>
```

Comment: [`localStorage.getItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem): _"A `DOMString` containing the value of the key. **If the key does not exist, `null` is returned.**"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time you run this code, `localStorage['storageArrObj']` does not exist yet:

1. `if (localStorage.getItem('storageArrObj') === ""){` is false.
2. `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storageArrObj'));` returns `null`.
3. Which is stored in `var parseStor =`.
4. `parseStor` is pushed into `storageArr`: `storageArr.push(parseStor);`
5. `storageArr`, with the `null` in there, is stored in `localStorage`.

Solution?

Replace:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('storageArrObj') === ""){
```

With:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('storageArrObj') === null){
```

Or with:

```
var stored = localStorage.getItem('storageArrObj');
if (stored === null || stored === ""){
```